# Call webservice method in updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, updatepanel

When I trying call web service method in update panel, I get error like below in Asp.net. How can i call web service method in updatepanel?

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem, it was related with web service authentication not related with update panel.